# pandas scatter plotting datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns of datetime.time's.  I'd like to scatter plot them.  I'd also like the axes to display the times, ideally.  But

```
df.plot(kind='scatter', x='T1', y='T2')
```

dumps a bunch of internal plot errors ending with a KeyError on 'T1'.

Alternatively, I try

```
plt.plot_date(x=df.loc[:,'T1'], y=df.loc[:,'T2'])
plt.show()
```

and I get 'Exception in Tkinter callback' with a long stack crawl ending in

```
return _from_ordinalf(x, tz)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 224, in _from_ordinalf
microsecond, tzinfo=UTC).astimezone(tz)
TypeError: tzinfo argument must be None or of a tzinfo subclass, not type 'str'
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Since you didn't specify a tz argument, I'm guessing its trying to parse it out of your datetime.  Just a guess.  Can you post an example of your datetime format?

Comment: These are datetime.time's, so TZ doesn't really make sense to me. 
`df.loc[:,'T1'].values[0] ==> datetime.time(0, 15, 43)`

Comment: Agreed.  Sorry, not much help

Comment: How about a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to recreate the error?

Answer (score 45):

Not a real answer but a workaround, as suggested by Tom Augspurger, is that you can just use the working line plot type and specify dots instead of lines:

```
df.plot(x='x', y='y', style=".")
```

Comment: But the figure produced in this way and the scatter plot are not the same.

Comment: To elaborate on @ZillGate comment - in this case, the x axis is just the list of "x" values. They are not necessarily in order, and they are not spaced appropriately (unless your x axis values are evenly spaced to begin with).

Comment: also instead of '.' one can use ',' for smaller points and 'o' for bigger points

Answer (score 11):

building on Mike N's answer...convert to unix time to scatter properly, then transform your axis labels back from int64s to strings:

```
type(df.ts1[0])
```

`pandas.tslib.Timestamp`

```
df['t1'] = df.ts1.astype(np.int64)
df['t2'] = df.ts2.astype(np.int64)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
df.plot(x='t1', y='t2', kind='scatter', ax=ax)
ax.set_xticklabels([datetime.fromtimestamp(ts / 1e9).strftime('%H:%M:%S') for ts in ax.get_xticks()])
ax.set_yticklabels([datetime.fromtimestamp(ts / 1e9).strftime('%H:%M:%S') for ts in ax.get_yticks()])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

*Not an answer, but I can't edit the question or put this much in a comment, I think.*

Here is a reproducible example:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [datetime.now() for _ in range(10)], 'y': range(10)})
df.plot(x='x', y='y', kind='scatter')
```

This gives `KeyError: 'x'`.

Interestingly, you *do* get a plot with just `df.plot(x='x', y='y')`; it chooses poorly for the default x range because the times are just nanoseconds apart, which is weird, but that's a separate issue. It seems like if you can make a line graph, you should be able to make a scatterplot too.

There is [a pandas github issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8113) about this problem, but it was closed for some reason. I'm going to go comment there and see if we can re-start that conversation.

Is there some clever work-around for this? If so, what?

Comment: A non-clever work-around is to convert to unix time (int64's), scatter plot, and then fiddle with axis ticks and labels.

Comment: @jma: instead of fiddling, you can try [`matplotlib.dates`](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic work around to get you started.

```
import matplotlib, datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def scatter_date(df, x, y, datetimeformat):
  if not isinstance(y, list):
      y = [y]
  for yi in y:
      plt.plot_date(df[x].apply(
          lambda z: matplotlib.dates.date2num(
              datetime.datetime.strptime(z, datetimeformat))), df[yi], label=yi)
  plt.legend()
  plt.xlabel(x)

# Example Usage
scatter_date(data, x='date', y=['col1', 'col2'], datetimeformat='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, but as a quick hack you can convert your DateTime to a timestamp using `.timestamp()` before loading into Pandas and scatters will work just fine (although a completely unusable x-axis).