# Python - How to plot day and time in string

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have this dataframe

```
    user_date   user_time
0   Thu         07:32:20
1   Wed         21:10:38
2   Fri         21:32:55
3   Sat         11:57:36
4   Fri         22:37:41
```

How to plot this dataframe with x is user_time with range 24hours and y is user_date.

In the meantime, thank you so much for your attention and participation.

Comment: is dataframe from csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem with `user_date` values, because if use `strings` get:

> TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot

One possible solution is convert them to [ordered categorical](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html) and plot by [`cat.codes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cat.codes.html).

Also plot [timedelata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23544011/2901002) is not implemented, so `user_time` was converted to [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) and then to `string`s by [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
days = ['Mon','Tue','Wed','Thu','Fri','Sat','Sun']
df['user_date'] = df['user_date'].astype('category', categories=days, ordered=True)

df['user_time1'] = pd.to_datetime(df['user_time']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df['user_date1'] = df['user_date'].cat.codes

ax = df.plot(x='user_time1', y='user_date1')

#set max and min values of axis
#https://stackoverflow.com/a/43460067/2901002
ax.set_yticks(range(7))
ax.set_yticklabels(days)
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Hi @jezrael, thanks for your help. I had this error: NameError: name 'ticker' is not defined
The plot missing some data in dataframe. How to keep the user_time? I don't want to change to second.

Comment: Yes, it was not easy, but now it should work. Please check solution.

Comment: Hi, I had this error : ** _astype() got an unexpected keyword argument 'ors' **. I using Python 3, but after removing  `ors=True, categories =days` everything ran fine! Thanks so much @jezrael

Comment: Do you think axis x? from 0 to 24?

Comment: I mean, I hope you can help me show all data of user_time. If I have 50 values of user_time, how to show all 50 value of that user on the plot ?

Comment: I think I get it - use `ax = df.plot(x='user_time1', y='user_date1', style=".")`

Comment: Thank you, idea is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29737663/2901002)