# Scatter plots matplotlib: Dealing with pandas datetime as index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

For some background info, I would like to create a scatter plot of different dataframes (each dataframe as been read from a csv) where the x value is the date and the y value is the water 'level'.

I've been trying to work out how I can make a scatter plot were the x value is the date or the index. After trying a number of options, I feel as though this is the 'best' error I have got so far:

```
    KeyError: "None of [DatetimeIndex(['2017-11-04 00:00:00',    
    '2017-11-04 01:00:00',\n ... '2018-02-26 11:00:00', '2018-02-26 
    12:00:00'],\n dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', length=2749, 
    freq=None)] are in the [columns]" .
```

I'm importing in my data from a csv file that looks something like this:

```
    date,               level
    2017-10-26 14:00:00, 700.1
    2017-10-26 15:00:00, 500.5
    2017-10-26 16:00:00, NaN
               ...
```

And I'm reading in the file like so:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", parse_dates=['date'],sep='\s*,\s*')
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df = df.loc['2017-11-04 00:00:00':]
```

Then this is my attempt at trying to plot the scatter plot:

```
ax = df.plot()
ax1 = df.plot(kind='scatter', x=df.index, y='level', color='r')

# ... my other dataframes I'd like to plot on the same graph...
```

I've only started using pandas so apologies for my lack of understanding. I've been fiddling about with what different ways of importing the csv ( the `sep='\s*,\s*'` was one attempt) but to no avail. I'd greatly appreciate any advice, thank you.

Edit: More thorough code

data1.csv:

```
date,level
2017-10-26 14:00:00,500.1
2017-10-26 15:00:00,600.5
2017-10-26 16:00:00,NaN
2017-10-26 17:00:00,NaN
2017-10-26 18:00:00,NaN
2017-10-26 19:00:00,600.5
2017-10-26 20:00:00,600.5
2017-10-26 21:00:00,700.0
2017-10-26 22:00:00,700.0
```

data2.csv:

```
date,level
2017-10-26 15:00:00,600.5
2017-10-26 16:00:00,NaN
2017-10-26 17:00:00,NaN
2017-10-26 18:00:00,NaN
2017-10-26 19:00:00,600.5
2017-10-26 20:00:00,600.5
2017-10-26 21:00:00,900.0
2017-10-26 22:00:00,900.0
2017-10-26 23:00:00,NaN
```

code:

```
import pandas as pd
import warnings
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

df = pd.read_csv("data1.csv", parse_dates=['date'],sep='\s*,\s*')
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df = df.loc['2017-10-26 15:00:00':]

df2 = pd.read_csv("data2.csv", parse_dates=['date'],sep='\s*,\s*')
df2.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df2 = df2.loc[:'2017-10-26 22:00:00']

ax1 = df.plot(kind='scatter', x='date', y='level', color='r')
ax2 = df2.plot(kind='scatter', x='date', y='level', color='g',      ax=ax1)

plt.show()
```

Comment: `x` should be a column name of your dataframe. Does `x="date"` not work? Or removing that argument completely?

Comment: That was originally what I was trying to do but unfortunately doesn't work , so where ```x='date'``` I get ```KeyError: 'date'```. And when I remove the 'x' argument I get a complaint saying that it has to be there. Also when I enter ```df.columns``` I only get 'level' back, which could be due to the fact I made the date my index, maybe?

Comment: Oh yes. Keep "date" as column to be able to use it inside the `x` argument.

Comment: So this may turn into a different question, but if I remove ```df.set_index('date', inplace=True)``` I get this error: ```ValueError: view limit minimum -36837.575000000004 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units
``` Do you think you'd be able to help me by shedding some light on this? As in I'm not sure how I can do both at the same time. This error shows up at the ```ax = df1.plot()``` line

Comment: Note that it's really cumbersome without [mcve]. So I can only comment on individual steps instead of just providing a working answer. It could well be that pandas is not able to plot scatter plots with dates. What you can always do is `plt.scatter(df["date"].values, df['level'].values)` instead.

Comment: One problem is also that you first `df.plot()` something. So that would probably be in different units, so if using matplotlib make sure to plot this also via `plt.plot` instead.

Comment: I improved my question to reflect the  Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable policy, including some sample csv files! And will remove the df.plot() now. The ```plt.scatter(df["date"].values, df['level'].values)``` did work for me! I will try and continue with that if the updated question is no use. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone runs into the same problem, I found a work around as described here: [pandas scatter plotting datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27472548/pandas-scatter-plotting-datetime)

I just added `style='o'` as seen below:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data1.csv", parse_dates=['date'],sep='\s*,\s*')
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df = df.loc['2017-10-26 15:00:00':]
ax = df.plot(style='o')

df2 = pd.read_csv("data2.csv", parse_dates=['date'],sep='\s*,\s*')
df2.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df2 = df2.loc[:'2017-10-26 22:00:00']
df2.plot(ax=ax,style='o')

plt.show()
```